# What's the importance of a non marring "rubber"?

Tags: product-recommendation, rubber, product-review

I have been looking at nail guns, and noticed that some of them are being advertised with non marring rubber tips and bumpers. Other brands not necessarily have these marketing outlined, but i still see the same tips and bumpers in the general location.

So question is, is there a value or importance to seeing "non marring" on a product? Or is it more of a marketing scheme?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The importance of non marring rubber is something to be considered. After all, you don't want the rubber scuffing the surface so you have to clean it off when you're done.

I have used many nail guns and I don't ever recall having one mar the surface to where I had to go back and clean or correct anything. I guess that could happen if the tips and bumpers were damaged/worn but not if they were properly maintained and replaced when needed.

I'd have to say it's a marketing scheme.